# Can I read a stream into a string including the Unicode BOM?

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, unicode, stream

`Content` is a stream containing Unicode characters. These can be UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32, and both endiannesses are possible.

Here is an instance with UTF-16 Unicode characters, complete including a BOM indicating Little Endian: `FF FE`.

I have a table of positions into this file. These positions are expressed in 16 bit characters. The BOM is at position 0, the 2 bytes after the BOM is position 1.

When doing

```
Dim oContent = New StreamReader(Content, Text.Encoding.Unicode)
Dim sContent = oContent.ReadToEnd
```

the BOM is completely swallowed:

```
?scontent
"AAaa" & vbCrLf & "BB111" & vbCrLf & "BB22222" & vbCrLf & "CCc" & vbCrLf & ...
```

When setting `detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks` to `False`:

```
    Dim oContent = New StreamReader(Content, False)
    Dim sContent = oContent.ReadToEnd
```

each character is representing a byte (but including the BOM):

```
?scontent
"��A" & vbNullChar & "A" & vbNullChar & "a" & vbNullChar & "a" & vbNullChar & vbCr & vbNullChar & vbLf & ...
```

A combination of the two

```
    Dim oContent = New StreamReader(Content, Text.Encoding.Unicode, False)
    Dim sContent = oContent.ReadToEnd
```

completely swallows the BOM again:

```
?scontent
"AAaa" & vbCrLf & "BB111" & vbCrLf & "BB22222" & vbCrLf & "CCc" & vbCrLf & "DDddd" & vbCrLf
```

**Question:** Can I somehow obtain the following into the string, exactly as in the stream?

```
Char    0     1     2     3
Byte    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
Content FF FE 41 00 41 00 61 00 ...
```

String.Substring(1, 3) should produce "AAa"

**If not:** Can I somehow detect, what BOM was provided and in how many bytes? (That differs among input files.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I somehow detect, what BOM was provided and in how many bytes?

If your file (or stream, whatever) is UTF-16 encoded, the BOM will always be 2 bytes: either `FE FF` or `FF FE`.

So if you really need to know the BOM (if your file is big-endian or little-endian), just read the first two bytes of your file (or stream):

```
Dim data as Byte()
Using fs = File.OpenRead("path/to/file/test.txt")
    Using binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fs)
        data = binaryReader.ReadBytes(2)
    End Using
End Using
```

If your file contains a BOM, `data` will now contain either `FE FF` or `FF FE`.

But you also said you already know your file is UTF-16 little-endian, so it's not clear to me what you're actually trying to achieve.

When you read the file/stream into a string, the string will not contain the BOM, as this does not make sense: the BOM is not part of the actual content, it's just a marker to indicate on how to interpret a bunch of bytes.

Also note that not every character in an UTF-16 String is represented by two 8-bit bytes: character can also be represented by 4 bytes.

If you want the content as string, just use `StreamReader(Content, Text.Encoding.Unicode)`.

For your example

> `String.Substring(1, 3)` should produce `"AAa"`

either just substract `1` from the index (`String.Substring(0, 3)`) or simply add a dummy 16-bit character to the string  (`Dim sContent = "x" + oContent.ReadToEnd`).

---

Update: To get the encoding of a file/stream, let the `StreamReader` do the work for you:

```
 Dim encoding as Encoding
 using sr = new StreamReader(filename, true)
    sr.peek()
    encoding = sr.CurrentEncoding
 end using
```

`encoding.BodyName` is now e.g. `utf-16BE`.

Comment: _But you also said you already know your file is UTF-16 little-endian_ -- I have updated my sloppily worded intro to the problem. So, in principle you suggest to write a function to inspect the first up to 4 bytes and possibly identify a BOM consisting of 2, 3 or 4 bytes and use these as a corrector to the positions pointing into the physical file, right?

Comment: @Herb OK, I understand. Yes, that would be my idea, but note that you can also simply use the `StreamReader` class to get the enconding. See my update.